# how to debug an error saying that a constructor does not take arguments

Tags: python

when a method call by use of an instance, the IDE displays an error that the constructor takes no argument on running the code

I have tried using double underscores in the *init* method

```
class Hotel():
      """displays a hotel's information"""

def __init__(name, cuisine):
    """shows details."""
    #self.name = name
    #self.cuisine = cuisine

def describe_restaurant(self):
    """prints two pieces information."""
    print("Welcome to" + name + ".")
    print("Where " + cuisine + "." "is offered")
    #+ "la" + cuisine_type + ".")


def open_restaurant(self):
    """Indicates when restaurant is open."""
    print("It is open at 09:00am everyday")

    my_hotel = Hotel('De La Rue', 'haute')
    print("My hotel's name is " + my_hotel.hotel_name.title() + "." )
    my_hotel.describe_restaurant()
    my_hotel.open_restaurant()
```

I expected the output my hotel's name is De La Rue

Comment: Is your code indented the same as it is here? The `__init__` method should be indented to be a member of the class. You'll also need a self argument.

Comment: @Sayse, why do you think this isn't Python 3?

Comment: @Holloway - It might be, but it is not a problem that is specific to python 3, but python in general

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `self` argument in your constructor

```
def __init__(self, name, cuisine):
```

(and you also need to uncomment out its contents)